# Convert BasicLSTMCell to bidirectional LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, bidirectional

Recently I tried to use BasicLSTMCell api from Tensorflow to generate video caption. I am working with a code that builds BasicLSTMCell in the following way:

```
self.lstm1 = tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(dim_hidden, state_is_tuple=False)
self.lstm2 = tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(dim_hidden, state_is_tuple=False)
```

Then uses it later as follows:

```
with tf.compat.v1.variable_scope("Encoding") as scope:  
      for i in range(0, self.n_video_lstm_step):
          if i > 0:
              scope.reuse_variables()

          with tf.compat.v1.variable_scope("LSTM1"):
              output1, state1 = self.lstm1(image_emb[:,i,:], state1)

          with tf.compat.v1.variable_scope("LSTM2"):
              output2, state2 = self.lstm2(tf.concat([padding, output1], 1), state2)
  
          out_list.append(tf.concat([output1, output2], 1))
```

I want these LSTM cells to be bidirectional for my requirement. I have tried using

```
keras.layers.Bidirectional(keras.layers.LSTM(dim_hidden, unit_forget_bias=True, unroll=True))
```

But it didn't work. Can anyone let me know how to make it work with bidirectional lstm.

Comment: To clarify, are you trying to use the bidirectional wrapper on existing LSTM implementation in Keras or you are creating a LSTM cells

Answer (score 0):

Based on the question you ask, `Convert BasicLSTMCell to bidirectional LSTM` - You can use the Bi-Directional RNN wrapper directly as shown in the code below. Do clarify how you are modifying the LSTM layer class that is causing the error you are facing. Ill update my answer accordingly.

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras import layers, Model, utils

X = np.random.random((100,10,3))
y = np.random.random((100,))

inp = layers.Input((10,3))
x = layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(8, return_sequences=True))(inp)
x = layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(8))(x)
out = layers.Dense(1, activation='softmax')(x)

model = Model(inp, out)
utils.plot_model(model, show_layer_names=False, show_shapes=True)

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')
model.fit(X, y, epochs=3)
```

```
Epoch 1/3
4/4 [==============================] - 5s 10ms/step - loss: 0.6963
Epoch 2/3
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 22ms/step - loss: 0.6965
Epoch 3/3
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 11ms/step - loss: 0.6976
<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f91066bf4c0>
```